# Firebase storage security rule parameter hash

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I work in an industry where there is an incredible amount of image hotlinking that takes place.

To help with this issue, it is very common to pass a hash when generating image URLs which allows the authenticity of querystring parameters to be verified, and which allows the storage location to do things like limit by IP, or a usage window (Supplied in the querystring parameters)

Is it possible to generate some type of hash in the security rules for firebase storage which can be used with a secret to ensure that the parameters supplied were generated by a trusted source?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to store a hash you'll need to compute it client-side, but it's easy to validate correctness of hashes using Rules!

```
rules_version="2"
service firebase.storage {
  match path/{docId} {
    // also available in md5, crc32 and crc32c flavors
    allow read, write: if docId == hashing.sha256(/* stuff */).toBase64();
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks super promising! I'm definitely going to have a dive into this! Thanks!

Comment: It's absurd how hard it is to find any of these functions in the docs. Stack overflow is often a better resource than the docs themselves.